# Rails delete automatic page content

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, html tag , script tag, head tag is created by itself even when I have written nothing in my index.html.erb or the controller method.

I want to output an empty page so that only that text appears which I write myself in controller or view, I don't want title, head, script, link to stylesheets, body and things like that to appear automatically on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need modify your application layout or create another. Or you may just be looking to `render plain: 'Your text'`. Either way you should look more into [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: render :plain worked but then I cannot put anything on the view... right?

Comment: It doesn't have a view, it only renders what you put in quotes. If you want to use a view you need to use a custom layout

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a layout that's yielding to your index.html.erb. You can tell a particular controller that you don't want to use a layout by adding this near the top of the controller code, for example in ApplicationController if you wanted to do it for your whole application:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout nil
```

Or if you wanted to use some custom layout (for example named "custom_layout.html.erb") with very little or nothing in it, you could specify in any of your controllers:

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  layout custom_layout
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, with respond_to you can exclude layout

`def index
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :layout => false}
   end
end`

This will give you just index template contain